How resolve a trait bound error in rust and rerun
I am using a tool called rerun to visualize images. Instead of having multiple functions for different data types like f32, u8 and so on, I thought I should make my function generic.
This is my attempt:
use num::Zero;
use opencv::core;
use opencv::prelude::*;
use rerun::external::ndarray;
use shared::Point3d;

trait AllowedTypes {}

impl AllowedTypes for f32 {}
impl AllowedTypes for u8 {}
impl AllowedTypes for u16 {}

pub fn visualize_image<T: AllowedTypes>(
    cv_image: &core::Mat,
    frame_idx: usize,
    rec: &rerun::RecordingStream,
    name: &str,
) where
    T: Zero + std::clone::Clone + std::fmt::Debug + core::DataType,
{
    let mat = cv_image.clone();

    let (width, height) = (mat.cols(), mat.rows());
    let size = (width * height * mat.channels() as i32) as usize;
    let mut image_data = vec![T::zero(); size];
    let data_typed = match mat.data_typed::<T>() {
        Ok(data_u8) => data_u8,
        Err(e) => panic!("Error extracting data: {}", e),
    };
    image_data.copy_from_slice(data_typed);

    let img_array =
        match ndarray::Array2::from_shape_vec((height as usize, width as usize), image_data) {
            Ok(img_array) => img_array,
            Err(e) => panic!("Error creating Array from vec<u8>: {}", e),
        };

    let rgb_image =
        match rerun::Image::from_color_model_and_tensor(rerun::ColorModel::L, img_array.clone()) {
            Ok(rgb_image) => rgb_image,
            Err(e) => panic!("Could not create image: {}", e),
        };
    rec.set_time_sequence("frame_idx", frame_idx as i64);
    // RGB image
    match rec.log(name, &rgb_image) {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(e) => panic!("Could not log image: {}", e),
    }
}

The error is:
    error[E0277]: the trait bound `rerun::TensorData: From<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>>` is not satisfied
  --> libs/visualization/src/visualizer.rs:39:15
   |
39 |         match rerun::Image::from_color_model_and_tensor(rerun::ColorModel::L, img_array.clone()) {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>>` is not implemented for `rerun::TensorData`, which is required by `rerun::TensorData: TryFrom<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <rerun::TensorData as From<&[f32]>>
             <rerun::TensorData as From<&[f64]>>
             <rerun::TensorData as From<&[i16]>>
             <rerun::TensorData as From<&[i32]>>
             <rerun::TensorData as From<&[i64]>>
             <rerun::TensorData as From<&[i8]>>
             <rerun::TensorData as From<&[rerun::external::re_arrow2::types::f16]>>
             <rerun::TensorData as From<&[u16]>>
           and 14 others
   = note: required for `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>` to implement `Into<rerun::TensorData>`
   = note: required for `rerun::TensorData` to implement `TryFrom<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>>`

I thought I could solve it by limiting the AllowedTypes to use the numerical types I am interested in. But that does not seem to work.
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "visualization"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rerun = "0.19.0"
opencv = "0.92.3"
num = "0.4"


Well, that if you also define struct MyStruct; impl AllowedTypes for MyStruct{}? Your function can be called for MyStruct then, but rerun doesn't support that struct. You need to point that out explicitly: something like where rerun::TensorData: TryFrom<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, ndarray::Dim<[usize;2]>>>, <rerun::TensorData as TryFrom<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, ndarray::Dim<[usize;2]>>>>::Error: std::error::Error should work (check for missing angle brackets above, it's a bit difficult to type in a comment). There's no common trait for such T's in rerun, as far as I can see.

Anyway, please make this a MRE: now core is undefined (and I can hardly guess where it comes from), and Cargo.toml would help to install all other dependencies at once.

There're two major problems blocking a straightforward implementation of this, which I'll explain one by one.

This issue cannot be solved by limiting the AllowedTypes to only the numerical types that TensorData originally accepts, as this is how Rust's type system works - all trait bounds are checked locally, meaning the compiler would know nothing about a type parameter T except for its bounds and the methods on them. Specifically, the compiler does not know what the "underlying type" of a type parameter is on the function side; this is a great difference from the C++ world.

Knowing the absence of adequate TryFrom causes this to fail, one would naturally like to implement TryFrom<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, D>> for TensorData where T: AllowedTypes mimicking the impl of preexisted ones inside rerun, trying to satisfy the bound of from_color_model_and_tensor, but unfortunately this would fail, as the orphan rule demands: we can’t implement external traits on external types. Here, ArrayBase and TensorData are both external types, and TryFrom is a std trait, all coming from outside our crate.


To solve the former issue, you can use a "dynamic dispatch" that the compiler would almost surely optimize out to transform a Vec<T> into a vec of T's "underlying" type, by recording the type information in an enum indicated by AllowedTypes, and use macros to efficiently expand all possible types inside the impl of TryFrom:
macro_rules! impl_allowed {
    ( $( $t:tt ),* ) => {
        #[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
        pub enum Type {
            $( $t ),*
        }

        $(
            impl AllowedTypes for $t {
                fn actual_type() -> Type {
                    Type::$t
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}

// ...
// at the end of `try_from` impl
paste! {
    let buffer = match T::actual_type() {
        $(
            Type::$t => unsafe {
                let (ptr, len, cap) = vec.into_raw_parts();
                let vec = Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr as *mut $t, len, cap);
                // use paste to format the typename to match `TensorBuffer`'s variant names
                TensorBuffer::[< $t:camel >](vec.into())
            }
        )*
    };
}

And, an easy way to bypass the latter one is to define a Local<T> that simply wraps any value inside of it, impl TryFrom<Local<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, D>>> for TensorData, and pass it as the parameter.
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Local<T>(pub T);

macro_rules! impl_try_from {
    ( $( $t:ident ),* ) => {
        impl<T: AllowedTypes, D: Dimension> TryFrom<Local<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, D>>> for TensorData {
            type Error = TensorCastError;

            fn try_from(value: Local<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, D>>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
                let value = value.0;
// ...


    // at call site
    let rgb_image = match rerun::Image::from_color_model_and_tensor(
        rerun::ColorModel::L,
        Local(img_array.clone()),
    ) {
        // ...

The full code is as follows:
#![feature(vec_into_raw_parts)]

use num::Zero;
use opencv::core;

use opencv::prelude::*;
use paste::paste;

use rerun::external::ndarray;
use rerun::external::ndarray::ArrayBase;
use rerun::external::ndarray::Dimension;
use rerun::external::ndarray::OwnedRepr;
use rerun::external::re_types::tensor_data::TensorCastError;

use rerun::TensorBuffer;
use rerun::TensorData;
use rerun::TensorDimension;

macro_rules! f_all_supported_types {
    ( $( $macro:ident ),* ) => {
        $(
            $macro!(f32, u8, u16);
        )*
    };
}

macro_rules! impl_allowed {
    ( $( $t:tt ),* ) => {
        #[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
        pub enum Type {
            $( $t ),*
        }

        $(
            impl AllowedTypes for $t {
                fn actual_type() -> Type {
                    Type::$t
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}

macro_rules! impl_try_from {
    ( $( $t:ident ),* ) => {
        impl<T: AllowedTypes, D: Dimension> TryFrom<Local<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, D>>> for TensorData {
            type Error = TensorCastError;

            fn try_from(value: Local<ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<T>, D>>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
                let value = value.0;
                let shape = value
                    .shape()
                    .iter()
                    .map(|dim| TensorDimension {
                        size: *dim as u64,
                        name: None,
                    })
                    .collect();

                let vec = if value.is_standard_layout() {
                    let (mut vec, offset) = value.into_raw_vec_and_offset();
                    // into_raw_vec_and_offset() guarantees that the logical element order (.iter()) matches the internal
                    // storage order in the returned vector if the array is in standard layout.
                    if let Some(offset) = offset {
                        vec.drain(..offset);
                        vec
                    } else {
                        debug_assert!(vec.is_empty());
                        vec
                    }
                } else {
                    value.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()
                };

                paste! {
                    let buffer = match T::actual_type() {
                        $(
                            Type::$t => unsafe {
                                let (ptr, len, cap) = vec.into_raw_parts();
                                let vec = Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr as *mut $t, len, cap);
                                TensorBuffer::[< $t:camel >](vec.into())
                            }
                        )*
                    };
                }
                Ok(Self { shape, buffer })
            }
        }
    }
}

f_all_supported_types!(impl_allowed, impl_try_from);

#[repr(transparent)]
struct Local<T>(pub T);

pub trait AllowedTypes {
    fn actual_type() -> Type;
}

pub fn visualize_image<T: AllowedTypes>(
    cv_image: &core::Mat,
    frame_idx: usize,
    rec: &rerun::RecordingStream,
    name: &str,
) where
    T: Zero + std::clone::Clone + std::fmt::Debug + core::DataType,
{
    let mat = cv_image.clone();

    let (width, height) = (mat.cols(), mat.rows());
    let size = (width * height * mat.channels() as i32) as usize;
    let mut image_data = vec![T::zero(); size];
    let data_typed = match mat.data_typed::<T>() {
        Ok(data_u8) => data_u8,
        Err(e) => panic!("Error extracting data: {}", e),
    };
    image_data.copy_from_slice(data_typed);

    let img_array =
        match ndarray::Array2::from_shape_vec((height as usize, width as usize), image_data) {
            Ok(img_array) => img_array,
            Err(e) => panic!("Error creating Array from vec<u8>: {}", e),
        };

    let rgb_image = match rerun::Image::from_color_model_and_tensor(
        rerun::ColorModel::L,
        Local(img_array.clone()),
    ) {
        Ok(rgb_image) => rgb_image,
        Err(e) => panic!("Could not create image: {}", e),
    };

    rec.set_time_sequence("frame_idx", frame_idx as i64);
    // RGB image
    match rec.log(name, &rgb_image) {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(e) => panic!("Could not log image: {}", e),
    }
}

